# How to create chunking of numpy.linespace() for large scale data

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm getting a memory error because the resulting data is too large since I am using a size of over billions.

What approach may I be using for chunking of data?

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is store all the resulting data, you can store first the chunked data to h5py. for reference http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/. Please elaborate your question

Try to create first a list of chunked size of your linspace total size.

Sample code:
where size is the shape of your linspace and limit is chunking value

```
    def create_list_sample_size(self, size, limit):
        list_sample_size= []
        while True:
            if size > limit:
                list_sample_size.append(limit)
                samples = samples - limit
            else:
                list_sample_size.append(limit)
                break

        return list_sample_size
```

Then create your own linspace method where you compute the chunked version:

```
    def generate_linspace(list_sample_size)
        for sample in list_sample_size:
            length += sample
        length -= 1
        for sample in samples:
            index += 1
            high_range = low_range + sample
            _sample = np.arange(low_range, high_range, dtype=dtype)
            step = delta / length
            if step == 0:
                _sample *= delta
            else:
                _sample *= step

            low_range = high_range
```

Comment: First, I want to get chunking of numpy linespace then stored chunked data to file. How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: Based on your question, I guess that you're experiencing a memory error since you're storing large size of data into array. which means your array reaches the maximum limit of what your ram can take.

Comment: Kindly see the edited answer. if this answer your question. then you can now store _sample to your file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What will you recommend for me to store the data faster in a file?

Comment: i suggest for you to use h5py for you to store large scale data faster in read/load